# SCIM Account provisionning not working with a Non-Gallery application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I followed the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-scim-provisioning in order to synchronize users of Azure AD into my application.

But it is not working :-(

Here is what I did:
[image: Provisionning settings]
1- I filled **Tenant URL** with the base URL of my application (so a Non-Gallery application) SCIM endpoints (e.g. /services/scim/v2/Users)
2- I tested the connection...
3- ...and got a successful feedback
4- Mappings appeared, but something strange came to me: it was talking about `customappsso` instead of my application
5- I selected scope **Sync only assigned users and groups** and I did the necessary into **Users and groups** screen

When consulting reports, an example of error:
[image]
1- a line concerning the export of a User
2- the activity concerning the report linked to selected line
3- the error details (404 Not Found). The mentionned requested URL is */xxx/services/scim/v2/Users* but from which host ?!? I don't know.

And obviously, I never got a call of SCIM REST Web Services of my application...

If someone could help me, it would be amazing :-)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found my problem...
There must be a problem between my seat and my keyboard!

All my SCIM endpoints are based on:

> /services/scim/v2

While Azure is querying:

> /services/scim/v2/scim

Pfff ...